# Where does fitnesse write my class logs

Tags: testing, fitnesse

I am new to fitnesse and starting with sample test cases.
I have a simple test case that has a

```
System.out.println("XYZ");
```

statement when ever the test case is executed.
I wanted to know where does FitNesse logs the System out log statements?

I can't see it in the FitNesse log files when I start FitNesse in the log enabled mode.

```
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 9999 -d . -l .

System info:
Windows 7 Enterprise edition, 64 bit
JDK 1.6b35
FitNesse Release 20121220
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System.out.println() goes to the output page. After your test completes, you will see a green, red, or yellow icon in the upper right. Click on that icon and it will go to the output page. Anything printed to standard out or standard error will go there.

If you want more detailed logging, you might want to build a logger class using Loj4j or an equivalent version in your fixture language.

Comment: Yes, that's where I found it. Thanks.